# .load content into div then fadeIn and fadeOut to other content

Tags: jquery

i´m german so i hope you canunderstand my question.

I have a problem with a script i use. I searched for a way to show content in a div and if the user click on another link the content is changed to other content. So i get it worked buti want also that the content is fadeIn whenits loaded (i get it working too) but if i click on another content link only the div fadeOut not the content.

Cansomeone please help me?

Here is the script

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.more').live('click',function(){
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        if ($('#ajax').is(':visible')) {
            $('#ajax').css('display','block').animate({opacity: 0.00}).empty();
        }
        $('#ajax').css('display','block').animate({opacity: 1.00},function(){
            $('#ajax').load('slide-fade-content.html #'+href,function(){
                $('#ajax').hide().fadeIn();
            });
        });
        return true;
    });
});
```

And really sorry for my bad english

Comment: You want to fade out the DIV not the content?

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think to fadeOut a div but not the content would be to place the content outside of the div then position the content over the div that fades in and out...

Alternatively change the style of the div rather than animating the opacity...